# Transfer an EDI or XML document from one machine to another machine through AS1 or AS2 or AS3 protocol

Tags: java, xml, edi

I want to write a simple java program to transfer an EDI or XML document from one machine to another machine using the AS1 or AS2 or AS3 protocol.

Can anyone help me to get started with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest updates to OpenAS2 have just been released and includes fairly documentation which should help anyone reading this to better understand setting up and using the OpenAS2 application from sourceforge

Answer (score 1):

All three use different transport layers (SMTP, HTTP, FTP).  AS2 would probably be easier.

This should put you in the right direction:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/

You would need it on both machines - to listen and send.  Also MDNs would need to be considered.  AS2 is a good fit for B2B, but the way your question is worded, that makes it seem like its not the case (machine to machine - on the same network), in which case it probably isn't the most efficient method of transferring files.

Comment: Thanks andrew..Have tried the link you posted..http://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/

Comment: No, I haven't. I've heard good things about it, and if you were looking for a starting point for a Java implementation (per your question), that would be it.  Personally, I think you're reinventing the wheel..you can find inexpensive AS2 software.

Comment: Yes andrew, I agree with you. We can find an inexpensive AS2 software. But, We planned to develop a software with different goal. for that we need to have our own. I started with OpenAS2, but i am facing small issues. I would be very happy if you suggest any other open source library, if you know.

Comment: If OpenAS2 is not to your liking, you can also check out: http://as2.mendelson-e-c.com/

Answer (score 1):

OpenAs2 would be a good choice. I have recently did some configurations on OpenAS2 to do the file transferring. If you have any questions on installing, configuring, applying certificates, running the OpenAS2 server on both Windows and Linux, I may be able to help you.

Comment: i need help in installing AS2, can you help me with this ?

Comment: At what place you need help? I can guide you through the installation.

Comment: can you provide me your email address ? so i can contact you there ?

Comment: at first i need to know which software do i prefer ? mendelson or openAs2 or as2secure ?

Comment: If you are much into mouse clicks, Mandelson would be a good choice, but if you need to go much into coding OpenAS2 would be a good choice. I have experience on OpenAS2.

Comment: i was able to do the basic setup, is there any guide to how i can create and AS2 ID, MDN URL and certificate to be exchange with another trading partner ?

Comment: - AS2 ID is something unique among 2 partners,like a reg num.

- MDN URL is an IP or a domain. if your OpenAS2 instance running on "www.yourserver.com", that will be your MDN URL.

- Certificates - Both partners should have their own PRIVATE Keys, and give their PUBLIC keys to other partner.

You can use these commands to create keys using OpenSSL.

`openssl req -new -nodes -keyout <partner>.prv -out <partner>.csr`

`openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in <partner>.csr -signkey <partner>.prv -out <partner>.cer`

.prv is pvt key
.cer is pub key

Creating keys will ask you to fill out some data. Fill.

Comment: thanks, but i received a .cer from remote partner, how do i create the other keys ?

Comment: .cer means your partners PUBLIC key. so create your Private and Public keys. then import your certificates to AS2 (for the partnership names that you have given)

Run openAS2
`cert import` <your AS2 ID> <your PVT key location>

then

`cert import` <your partner AS2 ID> <partner PUB key location>

You can define AS2 ID in your partnership.xml

Comment: can you explain me what are you trying to do with the .cer file received from remote partner. i did not understand what your trying to acheive with some of the commands that you typed there

Comment: 1. is your AS2 server running?
2. do you have your remote partner .cer file (public key) and your private key?

3. Do you have you public key? (which you need to give to your remote partner?

Comment: @masterFly I need your help in setting up the OpenAS2... Let me know how we can connect..my email id is jain.jayesh@tirnav.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a few more free solutions for AS2:

- If you are not an EDI provider and only one trading partner is
  enough, you may try [RSSBus AS2 connector](https://www.rssbus.com/solutions/as2/). It has web-interface
  and easy to start.
- There is also an opensource version of [Mendelson
  AS2](http://as2.mendelson-e-c.com/) with Swing GUI and a lot of features.

Both of them are not as flexible as [OpenAS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/), but have their own features and disadvantages.

Comment: RSSBus, by the way, has been renamed to [ARCESB](https://www.arcesb.com/download/)