# opensource software (Transfer an EDI/XML document + convert EDI-XML)

Tags: xml, edi

I need find a opensource software which is similar to the one mentioned in this writing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982596%28v=bts.10%29.aspx  (EDI solution for two trading partners that use different communication standards and want to exchange data.)  + Transfer an EDI/XML document from one machine to another machine ([Transfer an EDI or XML document from one machine to another machine through AS1 or AS2 or AS3 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460735/transfer-an-edi-or-xml-document-from-one-machine-to-another-machine-through-as1))

my english is not good enough,hope you understand

Comment: Try BOTS: http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml

Comment: I'm afraid the SO censors will probably close this question; requests for advice in choosing software are usually dismissed as "opinion based". Some cynical advice: the best way to ask such questions on StackOverflow is to pretend that you want to write the code yourself, and then people will happily respond that you don't need to, because a library already exists.

Comment: oh, I don`t know it (SO censors...). Thank you